# Read/Write data to/from Cloud Storage Bucket using gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, manjaro, gcsfuse

To mount Google Cloud Storage Bucket onto a directory on a local machine for processing.
Using a manjaro environment and installed gcsfuse manually.

in the gs://bucket01, there are directories containing jpg and json files

```
go get -u github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse
$GOPATH/src/github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/run/media/manjaro/gcp/key.json gcsfuse bucket01 /run/media/manjaro/gcp/bucket01

Using mount point: /run/media/manjaro/gcp/bucket01
Opening GCS connection...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.

cd /run/media/manjaro/gcp/bucket01
ls

# empty
# The expected outcome is data from gs://bucket01 populates /run/media/manjaro/gcp/bucket01
# Updates in /run/media/manjaro/gcp/bucket01 will also be seen in gs://bucket01
```

Am i using gcsfuse correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using [Implicit directories](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md)

> As mentioned above, by default there is no allowance for the implicit
> existence of directories. Since the usual file system operations like
> mkdir will do the right thing, if you set up a bucket's structure
> using only gcsfuse then you will not notice anything odd about this.
> If, however, you use some other tool to set up objects in GCS (such as
> the storage browser in the Google Developers Console), you may notice
> that not all objects are visible until you create leading directories
> for them.
>
> gcsfuse supports a flag called **--implicit-dirs** that changes the
> behavio

Comment: thank you. i've tried it and waited for 10 mins before ls on the directory. All the directories and files appeared